# zoomable sunburst(with label) with dynamic data

Tags: angular, angular7, sunburst-diagram

Working on zoomable sunburst and want to show title and other details . Data is in Json format fetching from api . Here is code link ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfjqu2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)) and getting output as shown in image:
[image]

Image not able to show title and details.